# 405 error with api.sap.com/api/IdDS_SCIM --> /Groups/{Id}

Tags: group, scim

I am trying to add group to existing user using SCIM API by following code and I am getting 405 error and not sure what is incorrect:

Below is help document from SAP I am trying to follow:
https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_FIELD_SERVICE_MANAGEMENT/fsm_scim_api/patch-scim-groups-members.html

I am using below SAP API tool to test:
https://api.sap.com/api/IdDS_SCIM/tryout

Note: All Header configuration correct since I have tested other method and it works.

Below is code generated by SAP API Tryout for sample:

```
var data = "{\n   \"schemas\": [\n      \"urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp\"\n   ],\n   \"Operations\": [\n      {\n         \"op\": \"add\",\n         \"path\": \"members\",\n         \"value\": [\n            {\n               \"value\": \"P000345\"\n            }\n         ]\n      }\n   ]\n}";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = false;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

//setting request method
//API endpoint for API sandbox 
xhr.open("PATCH", "https://awictqyv8.accounts.ondemand.com/service/scim/Groups/612fa668c2ddc128c9a9f70d");


//adding request headers
xhr.setRequestHeader("config_authType", "Basic");
xhr.setRequestHeader("config_packageName", "SCPIdentityServices");
xhr.setRequestHeader("config_actualUrl", "https://awictqyv8.accounts.ondemand.com/service/scim");
xhr.setRequestHeader("config_urlPattern", "https://{tenant}.{host}/scim");
xhr.setRequestHeader("config_apiName", "IdDS_SCIM");
xhr.setRequestHeader("DataServiceVersion", "2.0");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/scim+json");


//sending request
xhr.send(data);
```

**What am I doing wrong ?**

Comment: Just to say it explicitly, the error 405 Method Not Allowed is about `PATCH`. Is it the error you obtain through the Try Out Web site? Or is it through the Javascript sample which you have posted?